# How to get MIN, MAX and DIFFERENCE among rows with the same value in a certain column

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that is returning all RATINGS for STORES and a RATING_DATE. There isn't a fixed amount of ratings, it could be from one to unlimited rows that are returns that have the same STORE_ID value.

I'm trying to find the min, max, and difference for the STORE_ID, like in the example below:

Example data:

```
STORE_ID RATING_DATE    RATING
-------- -----------    ------
34       2015-01-20     4.0
34       2016-01-01     4.14
34       2017-01-01     4.56
34       2018-01-01     4.78
46       2015-01-01     3.5
46       2017-01-01     3.7
46       2016-01-01     3.95
```

Desired results:

```
STORE_ID DIFFERENCE MIN  MAX
-------- ---------- ---  ----
34      .78         4.0  4.78
36      .45         3.5  3.95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
create table #StoreRatings (
store_id    int,
rating_date date,
rating  float

)

insert into #storeRatings values (30,'2019-05-01',4.0)
insert into #storeRatings values (30,'2019-05-02',4.7) 
insert into #storeRatings values (31,'2019-04-01',1.7)
insert into #storeRatings values (31,'2019-05-01',4.7)

;with t1 as (
select s.store_id,
   min(s.rating) as min_rating,
   max(s.rating) as max_rating
 from #storeRatings s
group by s.store_id
)

 select t1.store_id,
     abs(t1.min_rating - t1.max_rating) as difference,
      t1.min_rating,
      t1.max_rating
 from t1
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers - and to make it clear that subqueries or CTEs are not needed here. We can have the same result without them. Use whatever is more clear to you:

```
select
     s.store_id,
     max(s.rating) - min(s.rating) as difference,
     min(s.rating) as min_rating,
     max(s.rating) as max_rating
from
     storeRatings as s
group by
     s.store_id
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with above answer completely and I would use similar approach however using different query. DDL and insert statement as below:

```
create table Ratings_SE (
store_id    tinyint,
rating_date date,
rating  float
)
go

insert into Ratings_SE values (34,'2015-01-20',4.0)
go
insert into Ratings_SE values (34,'2016-01-01 ',3.69) 
go
insert into Ratings_SE values (34,'2017-01-01',4.56)
go
insert into Ratings_SE values (34,'2018-01-01',4.78)
go
insert into Ratings_SE values (46,'2015-01-01',3.5)
go
insert into Ratings_SE values (46,'2016-01-01',3.95)
go
```

The select query which I would use to get desired result is as below:

```
 select store_id, (maxm - minm) as difference, minm as min, maxm as max from (select store_id, min(rating) minm, max(rating) maxm from Ratings_SE
 group by store_id)a
```

Below is the result set:

[image: Result Set]

Hope above helps.